# Lint restricted macro name list

Tags: lint, pc-lint

I've encountered a PC-Lint error message (e136) :

```
Illegal macro name  -- The ANSI standard restricts the use of certain names as
macros.  defined is on the restricted list.
```

I cannot find any reference to such a list in the ANSI C specifications. Is this list maintained by PC-Lint itself or is there an official list of Macro names forbidden in ANSI C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chances are that you're using a macro name such as `_HEADER_FILE_H_` which is reserved to the implementation and PC Lint is telling you about this error.

After removing the horizontal scroll bar, it appears that the name you are misusing is `defined`.  The C preprocessor uses the name `defined` for:

```
#if defined(SOME_MACRO)
```

You cannot, therefore, write:

```
#define defined(x)   ((x) != 0)
```

or anything similar.  You should treat `defined` as a keyword, at least in pre-processor directives (and you can't treat it as a macro outside of pre-processor directives).  Although you could use it as a variable name (and you could use `endif` and `define` and `elif` as variable names too), you'd be best off not using it and treating them as reserved words.

---

The C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says:

> #### 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> ¶1 Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and
>   optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions
>   subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file
>   scope identifiers.
>
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>     underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
>     with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
> - Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library
>     directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included;
>     unless explicitly stated otherwise (see 7.1.4).
> - All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with
>     external linkage.<sup>184)</sup>
> - Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with
>     file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.
>
> ¶2 No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
>   context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.
>
> ¶3 If the program removes (with `#undef`) any macro definition of an identifier in the first
>   group listed above, the behavior is undefined.
>
> <sup>184)</sup> The list of reserved identifiers with external linkage includes `math_errhandling`, `setjmp`, `va_copy`, and `va_end`.

Previous editions of the standard used very similar wording for the equivalent set of restrictions.

Comment: I'm quoting the error itself from the PC-Lint references. I presume that "defined" would be replaced by the invalid macro name